# How to reset sql admin password on Azure SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

How to reset the sql admin password on Azure SQL Managed Instance if there is only one user/admin and the admin password is lost/forgotten?

Could it be done via portal or using some script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to reset the password is to go to the Azure portal, open the instance details blade and press **Reset password** button:

[image: Reset sql admin password using the Azure portal]

As an alternative, you can use AzureRm.Sql PowerShell library and [Set-AzureRmSqlManagedInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/Set-AzureRmSqlInstance) command:

```
$InstancePassword = "Newpassword1234"
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $InstancePassword -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzureRmSqlInstance -Name "managedinstance1" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -AdministratorPassword $SecureString
```

You can also use Azure CLI with [az sql mi update](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/sql/mi?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-mi-update) command:

```
az sql mi update -g mygroup -n myinstance -i -p mypassword
```